# For Loop to Delete Potentially Multiple Columns in Google Apps Script

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet where the user can select one of several options in Column A. There are 7 cells within this column where they can select an option. If the user chooses "Omit Day", I need the corresponding column to delete (this gets transferred to a different sheet). I have the following code:

```
//Delete all cells set to 'Omit Day'.
  var omit_vals = [];
  var impact_locs = ['A22', 'A23', 'A24','A25', 'A26', 'A27', 'A28'];
  var hazard_briefing_placement = ['B13', 'C13', 'D13', 'E13', 'F13', 'G13', 'H13'];
  var hazard_date_briefing_placement = ['B12', 'C12', 'D12', 'E12', 'F12', 'G12', 'H12'];
    for (var zx = 0; zx < 7; zx++){
     var range_omit = String(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('main_gen!'+impact_locs[zx]).getValue());
      if (range_omit == 'Omit Day'){
      omit_vals = zx;
        var range_omit_del = body.getRange(hazard_briefing_placement[omit_vals]);
        range_omit_del.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);
        var range_omit_del2 = body.getRange(hazard_date_briefing_placement[omit_vals]);
        range_omit_del2.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);
        Logger.log(omit_vals);
    }
  }
```

`Omit_vals` properly stores the correct value of the column I would like to delete. So with the way the code is currently written, the first time it loops through it deletes the correct column. However, there is now one less column for when it loops through the second time, so when there is a second (or third, or fourth, etc.) column it needs to delete, it now is off by one column due to there being one less to begin with. I am not sure how I can account for this. Any idea of what I need to correct? I am pretty sure it is within the `hazard_briefing_placement[omit_vals]` line, but I am not sure how to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your issue because I couldn't test it, how about modifying from `for (var zx = 0; zx < 7; zx++){` to `for (var zx = 6; zx >= 0; zx--){`? If this was not the direct solution, I apologize.

Comment: That nearly works. For some reason it keeps deleting one extra column at the left end. Aside from that hiccup, it deletes the rest of the columns as wanted.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that my comment didn't resolve your issue. In the current stage, I think that it is required to confirm your current issue. In order to test the script, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating the current issue? Of course, please remove your personal information. By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Ok, here is a version you can test: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e5fhYLGvCQ7OEN2Zp9v311L93IxC0tg-QUgnHf2EGmM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your script in your share Spreadsheet, I can see various scripts except for the script in your question. Can you provide a simple sample script for replicating your current issue using your script in your question? Because from your current script, I cannot see the vision of your goal. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: I changed it to match what you had suggested earlier. It is under the comment: `///////THIS IS THE SECTION I AM TRYING TO GET TO WORK`. I appreciate you looking at this!

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot see the vision of your goal from your shared Spreadsheet and script. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Please add on your sample sheet a version of "What should happen" so we can better understand your specification.

Comment: @Tanaike your original solution actually did work perfectly. The reason it was deleting an extra cell is because of a line of code elsewhere. I removed that line and it works exactly as it should. Thanks! If you post that as an answer I will accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: @hunter21188 Thank you for replying and your concern. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modification point of your script is as follows.

#### From:

```
for (var zx = 0; zx < 7; zx++){
```

#### To:

```
for (var zx = 6; zx >= 0; zx--){
```

- When the column is deleted with ascending, 1st loop work. But at 2nd loop, the script is not correctly worked because the column number is changed by deleting the column at the 1st loop. This is the reason of your issue.
- When the column is delete with descending, the script is correctly worked because the column number is not changed.
- Of course, even when the column is deleted with ascending, when the column number is updated every loop, the script is correctly worked. But I think that the descending loop becomes simpler script.